# Getting total number of employee from multiple records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a timecard file that list the daily hours for each employee. I have figured out, using a query, how to get the total number of hours but I also need the total number of employees. I have searched here and on other places and tried just about everything and nothing works. I am sure it is something pretty simple but I just cannot seem to get the total number of employees. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
The main file is called **Timecards** and I link to a file call **Employees** using the field **employee number** to get the employee name. There are other fields in Timecards namely "Job No", "Job Description" and "Type of Hours"( such as regular and overtime) that I wanted on the summary report but I did not realize that a employee could have two entries in those fields. So that is why I could not get the total employees to come out right when using those fields. 
I was finally able to create a query and print a report with the total employees using fields that only appear once in the Timecards file. So unless someone knows how to count total lines is a report I will stick with the report I have that works.

Comment: We can not help you without seeing any code or table definitions.

Comment: `Select employeeID, sum(daily_hours) from table group by employeeID`.  Vladimir's right though. W/o any tables or query, we can't help much.  anything we provide won't be tailored to your specific problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the code" Sum(Timecards.hours) AS SumOfhours
FROM Timecards
GROUP BY Timecards.employee_no; From this I will link to the employee table to get the employee name and print a report listing each employee and their hours with the total number of employees at the bottom. I have tried Count, DCount and just about everything else with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vladimir, it helps to post what you expect to see and what kind of tables you are working with. However, I have been in the same situation. Maybe this is a good starting point in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalNumberEmployees FROM TheTableShowingEmployees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a question with:

1. A problem statement
2. A list of expected results
3. Sample Code tried
4. Table structures involved (Including relevant fields, data types, and tableNames)

Will get you better results.  Show your work, we'll show you ours!

Given limited information so far this is the best I can come up with

- I use a left join incase some of the employees haven't reported hours yet and you want all employees.
- I use coalesce to change null hours to 0.
- I assume that Employees Table exists and it joins to timecard on Employee_no.
- I assume firstName and LastName are in the
  employeetable

.

```
SELECT coalesce(Sum(T.hours),0) AS SumOfhours, E.FirstName, E.LastName
FROM Employees E
LEFT JOIN Timecards T
  on T.Employee_no = E.Employee_no
GROUP BY E.FirstName, E.Last_name
```

Also note you can edit your question don't comment on it; it makes it difficult to follow.. and last but not least .... Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Well after much searching and testing I finally found a post from 2009 that took care of my problem.

`If you want to count groups, you might need to add a running sum text box in 
the group header. For instance, if your report contains orders and order 
details but you want to count the number of unique orders, you can't use a 
text box in the report footer with a control source like:
=Count(OrderID)
This expression will count orders and details. 
You can add a text box in the Order header:
Name: txtOrderCount
Control Source: =1
Running Sum: Over All
Visible: No
Then add a text box in the Report Footer section:

### Control Source: =txtOrderCount

Duane Hookom
Microsoft Access MVP`

Thanks for all the help.